# OData Containment

Tags: odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I just learn that with the [Contained] attribute I can define a contained collection. This means the collection is no more accessible from my root oData system. Ok fine, but here is my model:

I have a user that have addresses
The user has invoices
Each invoice can have one or two addresses from the user.

On which collection should I add the contained attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this completely depends on your domain model. The advice I would give is to use OData containment sparingly. It really only makes sense to use it if the entity you are marking as being a contained entity cannot exist outside of the context of the parent entity. Because of this constraint I think the use cases for OData containment are few and far in between. The advantage over a separate controller is that it can make more sense from an architectural standpoint. However your controllers become more bloated and it is more work to maintain the `ODataRouteAttributes` on your methods. Something which is not necessary when using convention based routing.

The example on [the guide to set up OData containment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/odata-containment-in-web-api-22) explains it somewhat. It falls a bit short on why you would use it. Note that the `PaymentInstrument` entity has no foreign key to `Account`. This means that there is no separate table where the `PaymentInstrument` information is stored. Instead it is stored directly on the `Account` record. Yet is still defined as a `Collection<T>` so it is probably stored as JSON or across multiple columns. This might not necessarily be the case, but from a code standpoint the database could look like that.

To further explain OData containment let's say we have the domain model below.

```
public class HttpRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual HttpResponse HttpResponse { get; set; }
}

public class HttpResponse
{
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see the `HttpResponse` class has no navigation property to `HttpRequest`. Therefore it makes no sense to want to call `GET odata/HttpResponses` as we would be getting all `HttpResponses`, but not the `HttpRequest` they are linked to. In other words the `HttpResponse` class is useless without the context i.e. the `HttpRequest` for which it was produced.

The `HttpResponse` class not having any meaning outside of the `HttpRequest` context makes it a perfect candidate for OData containment. Both classes could even be saved on the same record in the database. And because it's not possible to perform a GET/POST/PUT/DELETE without specifying the id of the `HttpRequest` to which the `HttpResponse` belongs, it makes no sense for the `HttpResponse` class to have its own controller.

Now, back to your use case. I can see two likely domain models.

1. The entities `User`, `UserAddress`, `Invoice` and `InvoiceAddress`.

In this first option every single entity has their own designated address entity. OData containment would make sense here using such a design as the address entities do not exist outside of their respective parent entity. A `UserAddress` is always linked to a `User` and an `InvoiceAddress` is always linked to an `Invoice`. Getting a single `UserAddress` entity makes less sense because using this domain model one shouldn't care where the single address is. Instead the focus lays more on what the persisted addresses for this single `User` are. It's also not possible to create a `UserAddress` without specifying an existing `User`. The `UserAddress` entity relies on the `User` entity **entirely**.

2. The entities `User`, `Invoice`, `TypedAddress` and `Address`.

In this second option the `Address` entity is stand-alone. It exists separately from the other entities. Since an address boils down to a unique location on this planet it is only saved once. Other entities then link to the `Address` entity via the `TypedAddress` entity where they specify what kind of address it is in relation to the entity linking to it. Getting a single `Address` makes perfect sense using this domain model. An addressbook of the entire company could easily be retrieved by requesting `GET odata/Addresses`. This is where OData containment does not make sense.

Do note that it is possible to use the ODataConventionModelBuilder to configure containment. Because you do not need to add the `ContainedAttribute` to your class, this has the advantage of not polluting your data layer with a reference to the OData library. I would recommend this approach. In your situation I would expect to have the configuration below.

```
var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
modelBuilder
    .EntityType<User>()
    .ContainsMany(user => user.UserAddresses);
modelBuilder
    .EntityType<Invoice>()
    .ContainsMany(invoice => invoice.InvoiceAddresses);
```